# Why can't my Python calculator accept values larger than single digit?

Tags: python, calculator

So I tried to make a Python calculator, recently started to look into the language. Here is the code I made:

```
#Calculator v2

def Calculator(num1, figure, num2):
    if figure == "+":
        total = num1 + num2

        print(total)
    elif figure == "/":
        total = num1 / num2

        print(total)
    elif figure == "-":
        total = num1 - num2

        print(total)
    else:
        total = num1 * num2

        print(total)


print("##Write your forumla below: #############")
print("##Operators to choose from are + - * / ##")

num1, figure, num2 = input()
Calculator(int(num1), figure, int(num2))
```

Why doesn't the input accept larger numbers than 9? Once they get double digit it throws the following error code:

"too many values to unpack (expected 3)"

Could anyone please help? :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in:

```
num1, figure, num2 = input()
```

This assumes that you have **exactly** 3 characters. `num1` will be the first, `figure` the second, `num2` the third.

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) instead:

```
import re

num1, figure, num2 = re.split('([+-/*])', input())
```

Example input:

```
12*45
```

Output:

```
['12', '*', '45']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that your app isn't able to accept numbers with more than 1 digit.
The issue at hand is as follows:

when calling input() you're accpeting a string input.
When using

```
num1, figure, num2 = input()
```

Python will try to break your input into 3 arguments, but for example `22` can't be broken into 3 arguments, just 2. thus the error you're seeing

You can take a different approach

You can use spaces to split the formula

```
formula = input() # 22 + 10
num1, op, num2 = formula.split(' ') # ('22','+','10')
```

Another option, is to parse the formula yourself, and break the formula via the op character, then a validate you have a valid formula structure